# Loop issue in C# Comparing two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am creating a C# GUI application and I am having problems with my loop, the application gets .txt file with student driver exam answers A,B,C or D from each on a septate line and then it compares it with the correct answers in the array in the code. My loop is always giving me that all answers are incorrect regardless of the answers being correct or incorrect.

My interface

[image] [image]

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Mohammad_Saad_Assignment_1_Part_2_Sec_B
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Acutal answers
    string[] correctAnswers = { "B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B", 
            "C", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A" };

    //Student answers array of size 20
    string[] studentAnswers = new string[20];

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.Items.AddRange(correctAnswers);

        //Opening a new file.
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        //Dismiss user cancelation so application dosnt crash.
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path.Text = open.FileName;
        }

        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(open.FileName);
        int index = 0;

        while (index < correctAnswers.Length && !sReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            correctAnswers[index] = sReader.ReadLine();
            index++;
        }
        foreach (string str in correctAnswers)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(str);
        }

        btnOpen.Enabled = false;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int questionNumber = 1;
        int answersCorrect = 0;
        int answersIncorrect = 0;
        do
        {
            if (studentAnswers[i] == correctAnswers[i])
            {
                answersCorrect++;
            }
            if (studentAnswers[i] != correctAnswers[i])
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add("Question " + questionNumber);
                listBox3.Items.Add("Incorrect");
                answersIncorrect++;
            }
            i++;
            questionNumber++;
        }

        while (i != 20);
        lblCorrect.Text = answersCorrect.ToString();
        lblInCorrect.Text = answersIncorrect.ToString();
        if (answersCorrect >= 15)
        {
            txtResults.Text = "PASS";

        }
        if (answersCorrect < 15)
        {
            txtResults.Text = "FAIL";

        }

        btnMark.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnOpen.Enabled = true;
        btnMark.Enabled = true;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox3.Items.Clear();
        txtResults.Clear();
    }
}
}
```

The issue is I think is in the Mark button (button 1)
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the character case in your file? Are they UpperCase "A,B,C..." or LowerCase "a,b,c"?

Comment: Hi Alireza, i am using upper case as well, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this code block:

```
while (index < correctAnswers.Length && !sReader.EndOfStream)
{
    correctAnswers[index] = sReader.ReadLine();
    index++;
}
foreach (string str in correctAnswers)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(str);
}
```

to:

```
while (index < correctAnswers.Length && !sReader.EndOfStream)
{
    studentAnswers[index] = sReader.ReadLine();
    index++;
}
foreach (string str in studentAnswers)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this line when you are reading in the student answers:

```
correctAnswers[index] = sReader.ReadLine();
```

It should be:

```
studentAnswers[index] = sReader.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Exactly. Then the same array is shown in both list boxes. But when he checks the results, he compares array `{ null, null, null, ... }` to `{ "B", "D", "A", ...}`. An unrelated suggestion would be to verify the file contents. A string like `"A "` (with a space) from the file could lead to more subtle errors.

Answer (score 2):

In general, using the debugger, and executing the code step by step will help you.